# Prevent User from updating OS versions

Tags: android

I have a requirement that when the user is in range of my WIFI, user should not upgrade OS version. As of now I have following two thoughts.

1)Removing the Updater.apk from `system/app` folder when user enters into range of WIFI and replacing the Updater.apk into the same path `system/app` when user go out of range of WIFI.

Is there any way to access `system/app` folder ?

2)I want to know the OS up-gradation download URL, so that I can block this URL from my WIFI.

Could any one tell me the OS up-gradation download URL?

Is download URL same for all the manufactures?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you a maker of the devices or a provider of WiFi? In the first case, you can modify that apk; in the 2nd case, you have no access to system apps. I mean, if the WiFi provider can hack into user data, it is a hole in security.

Comment: I am developing a android application. just I want to stop auto OS upgrade for the device.

Comment: You need root acces in rooted devices.

Comment: Hmmm... You want your application to take control over the whole device, sort of. What kind of application is that? Do you want to disable upgrades while your app is running, or in general?

Comment: This application is intended to use for my company devices. Generally , I want to disable updates when user connected to network(WIFI) in my company.